# Stochastic integral with Poisson random measure

Tags: stochastic-integrals, levy-processes

The following is what I read in paper and I am confused by some parts.

We consider a one-dimensional Itô semimartingale $X$ which is defined
on some probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\{\mathcal F_t\},P)$ and can be represented
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
X_t=&X_0+\int_0^tb_sds+\int_0^t\sigma_sdW_s+\int_0^t\int_{\mathbb R}\delta(s,z)1_{\{|\delta(s,z)|\leq1\}}(p-q)(ds,dz)\\
&+\int_0^t\int_{\mathbb R}\delta(s,z)1_{\{|\delta(s,z)|>1\}}p(ds,dz),
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $W$ is a standard Brownian motion and $p$ is a Poisson random measure on $\mathbb R^+\times \mathbb R$ with compensator $q(dt,dz)=dt\otimes dz$. Assume that for some $r\in[0,2]$, $$|\delta(\omega,t,z)|^r\wedge1\leq J(z)$$ where $J$ is a Lebesgue-integrable function on $\mathbb R$. If $r=1$, we can rewrite the above equation (up to modifying $b_s$) as
$$X_t=X_0+\int_0^tb_sds+\int_0^t\sigma_sdW_s+\int_0^t\int_{\mathbb R}\delta(s,z)p(ds,dz).$$
My questions are as follows:

1. It seems that the Levy measure of $p$ is Lebesgue measure. However, a Levy measure $\nu$ should satisfy $\int_\mathbb Rx^2\wedge1\nu(dx)<\infty$. Why is the compensator $Q$ has the form $dt\otimes dz$ ?
2. If the Levy measure is the Lebesgue measure, for the case $r=1$, 
   \begin{equation}
   \begin{aligned}
   &E\int_0^t\int_{\mathbb R}|\delta(s,z)|1_{\{|\delta(s,z)|\leq1\}}p(ds,dz)\\
   =&E\int_0^t\int_{\mathbb R}|\delta(s,z)|1_{\{|\delta(s,z)|\leq1\}}ds\otimes dz\\
   \leq&E\int_0^t\int_{\mathbb R}|J(z)|ds\otimes dz\\
   <&\infty.
   \end{aligned}
   \end{equation}
   Therefore, we can decompose $\int_0^t\int_{\mathbb R}\delta(s,z)1_{\{|\delta(s,z)|\leq1\}}(p-q)(ds,dz)$ into two parts and combine $\int_0^t\int_{\mathbb R}\delta(s,z)1_{\{|\delta(s,z)|\leq1\}}p(ds,dz)$ with 
   $\int_0^t\int_{\mathbb R}\delta(s,z)1_{\{|\delta(s,z)|>1\}}p(ds,dz)$ to get 
   $\int_0^t\int_{\mathbb R}\delta(s,z)p(ds,dz)$. Since $$\int_\mathbb R|\delta(s,z)|1_{\{|\delta(s,z)|\leq1\}}dz\leq\int_\mathbb R|J(z)|dz<\infty,$$
   we can define a new drift
   $b_s'=b_s-\int_\mathbb R\delta(s,z)1_{\{|\delta(s,z)|\leq1\}}dz$ which is still locally bounded.
   Is my computation of the transform correct?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

> It seems that the Levy measure of p is Lebesgue measure. However, a Levy measure ν should satisfy ∫ℝx2∧1ν(dx)<∞. Why is the compensator Q has the form dt⊗dz ?

I don't think the Levy measure of $p$ is Lebesgue measure.  I think it is dirac measure at 1, i.e. $\delta_1$.  This is because all jumps are of size 1 (hence the subscript) and the intensity is a constant 1 (coefficient in front of $\delta_1$.  I think you might be confusing Levy measure with the intensity of a Poisson measure.  Since the compensator has form $q(dt,dz)=dt\otimes dz$, the process $p$ is a random Poisson measure with intensity 1 on $\mathbb{R}^+ \times \mathbb{R}$. That might clear up some confusion?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Would you please give some reference on the definition of levy measure and the intensenty?

Comment: http://homepages.ulb.ac.be/~cazizieh/Levy_files/3.%20levy%20processes%20-%20levy%20ito%20and%20path%20properties%20part%202.pdf